# Pass invisible or hidden parameters using routerLink Angular

Tags: angular, router, routeparams

I have router link like below:

```
<button class="take-a-tour-btn" [routerLink]="['/dashboard', {'showTour':'show'}]">
```

I want to pass parameter `showTour`. But, when I do this, the parameter is visible in `url` and I would like to hide it. I have gone through so many references(which says about optional parameters) ,but with no success in my case. How could I solve this?

Comment: {'showTour':'show'} , this will be same all the time ?

Answer (score 41):

You can use **History state** to pass dynamic data to the component you want to navigate to, without adding them into the URL, like so :

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/user', { state: { orderId: 1234 } });
```

or

```
<a [routerLink]="/user" [state]="{ orderId: 1234 }">Go to user's detail</a>
```

and you can get it this way

```
constructor() {
  this.router.events
   .pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart))
   .subscribe((e: NavigationStart) => {
    const navigation  = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
    this.orderId = navigation.extras.state ? navigation.extras.state.orderId : 0;
   });
 }
```

Comment: Hi may I check with you if the approach above will also hide the dynamic data in Network Tab under F12?

Comment: @Fateh Mohamed
this.router.getCurrentNavigation() returns null.

Comment: getCurrentNavigation have to be called it inside your constructor

Comment: its working perfect but after refresh component  state will be undefined,can you tell me how to handle this scenario?

Comment: check my update, try to navigate to router events changes

Comment: with links :
`<a [routerLink]="['dashboard', YourParamsHere]" skipLocationChange>`

Answer (score 17):

I'm not sure, if there is a way to do it, because the data need to be presented in the URL string.

My suggestion is using global service which be store needed data. For example:

```
//some dataService, which store your needed data.
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

   _showTour: string;

   set showTour(value: string) {
      this._showTour = value;
   }

   get showTour(): string {
       return this._showTour;
   }

   constructor() {}

}
```

and use it in your navigation component in this way:

```
//your navigation component
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
       <button class="take-a-tour-btn" (click)="onClick()">
    `
})
export class SomeComponent {
    constructor(private dataService: DataService, private router: Router) { }

    onClick() {
        this.dataService.showTour = 'show';
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    }
}
```

You will may use the same service in your Dashboard Component, and get needed value, f.e. in this way:

```
//your dashboard component
@Component({
    selector: 'my-dashboard',
    template: `
       <h1>{{ showTour }}</h1>
    `
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

    showTour: string;

    constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.showTour = this.dataService.showTour;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jaroslaw K..  I pass the parameters only from one location. So, I don't need that service anywhere else. Using a separate service for that small data is not good I think.

Comment: @SaiUnique Never get hung up on the 'size' of a service in Angular. In fact don't even think of them as 'services' - think of them as 'shared objects'.

Comment: You can also hack away with something like `this.router['navigationData'] = data` and `let data = this.router['navigationData']` on the other side. The router is initialized only once and it's still a dictionary-like javascript object anyways, so I'm using this for now and I really hope that this remains possible in the next angular versions. The bad part is that you need to be responsible, because this way stores data not only between navigations, but on a global ng service, thus, it would be wise to clean up on the receiving side.

Comment: @Felype This seemed like a good choice, but unfortunately, this didn't work on Angular 7.

Comment: It won't work if you're moving from one module to the next and the provider for router is different, in my application I have only 1 provider for router and it's on the root app module, that thing that I said I do is a gimmick because I know the router is a javascript object that angular loads and keeps in memory, you could use any service for that purpose though.

Answer (score 12):

Use state to pass hidden parameters and history to read 'em.

**First component:**

```
this.router.navigate(
      [`/dashboard/roles/${id}`],
      { state: { navSettings: navSettings } });
```

**Second component:**

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id;
    this.initNavSettings(history.state.navSettings);
}
```

Comment: This is best solution, it just needs a bit more of comments. `state` is in facts [Javascript history state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/state) so there is no need to use `Router`/`ActivatedRoute` to access it, just use plain Javascript `history.state`.

Comment: Not only does this work perfectly and in a clean ad fast way but this also works through page refreshes

Answer (score 4):

```
<button class="take-a-tour-btn" [routerLink]="['/dashboard', {'showTour':'show', skipLocationChange: true}]">
```

Try using skipLocationChange property.

Comment: Thank you @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd. The `parameters` still appear in `url` with your solution. My `url` changes when that link is clicked. But, parameters which I pass should not appear in `url`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your component:(I am using it with Angular 5.x)

```
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'], {skipLocationChange: true, replaceUrl: false});
```

Comment: brilliant! Thanks

Comment: Thanks! Glad it helped. BTW, it will disable history navigation(back and forward button on browser) I believe.

Answer (score 0):

@AddWeb @SailiUnique

Your solution works but you don't have to put the property in the [routLink]. The correct place is outside it as any property.

Like this:

`<div class="row inline rowItem" [routerLink]="['/businessPartnerDetails']" [queryParams]="{ id: bpItem.id, bp: bpItem.companyName}" skipLocationChange=true (click)="onViewDetails(bpItem)">`

Comment: `queryParams` are visible in the `URL`.

Answer (score 0):

The response isn't exactly efficient  because the skipLocationChange don't change the current route on browser url and if you want to go back later, you backed from the first route.

For example if you were on home page and use this:

`<button class="take-a-tour-btn" [routerLink]="['/dashboard', {'showTour':'show', skipLocationChange: true}]">Go to dashboard</button>`

if you want to back from `dashboard` to `home` you can't do that with object `location`, in this case, you need to use `Router` and specify an exactly route (`/dashboard`).

But this in much cases this is a bad solution, and the browser routing don't change from `/home` to `dashboard`.

**Inconvenients**:

- The browser don't refresh to the correct url
- You can't go back from `dashboard` (current route)

You can create the data service or check the official [angular router docs](https://angular.io/api/router/Router)