# Mask URL Parameters

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I hide url parameters in an Angular 2+ app? My url looks like this and I would like to hide all the data after "details"

```
http://localhost:4200/booking/details;caseData=%7B%22getAllCaseInfoWithCASR...
```

I am doing a routing call like this

`this.router.navigate(['/booking/details', { caseData : JSON.stringify(this.caseData) }])`;

My routes array includes

```
{ path: 'booking/details', component: DetailsComponent, data: { title: extract('Details') } },
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass invisible or hidden parameters using routerLink Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46905336/pass-invisible-or-hidden-parameters-using-routerlink-angular)

Comment: @KrishnaMohan there is no official answer in that post