# is there any security advantage of hiding url parameters

Tags: angular, security, url, https

I am building a web app that needs to be secure. My question is: Is there any security advantage of hiding route parameters? And if so which ones? I am using angular.

[Here is an example of hiding route parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46905336/pass-invisible-or-hidden-parameters-using-routerlink-angular), are there any advantages in doing so?

**UPDATE**:
What I mean by hiding url paramters is instead of having a url the reads

```
'https//yourApp/user/<user_id here>'
```

to have one that reads

```
'https//yourApp/user'
```

but behind the scenes you are processing the request using the user id.

Comment: What do you mean by `route parameters`? The ones you send to API? Or the ones you navigate by inside Angular? What do you mean by "hiding"?

Comment: @HarunYilmaz The question has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answered in the information security stack exchange
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/214034/is-there-any-security-advantage-of-hiding-url-parameters.

Basically the answer is it depends on the kind of information you url paramters are exposing. If the infomation is sensitive there is definately an advantage in hiding the url paramters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app-routing.module.ts` to manage your routes

Comment: This does not answer the qustion in any way